# Chrome extension tabs permissions shows "Read your browsing history"

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am creating an extension that can save all current tabs when a user clicks on a "save this session" button. A function call triggers this code:

```
// Go through all tabs in current window
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {

    // Iterate through each tab
    tabs.forEach(function (tab) {

        // Gets tab.url, tab.title, tab.favIconURL
    });
});
```

I don't call this function anywhere else and it is ONLY triggered by a user gesture. There are similar questions on SO, but they don't clearly explain why requesting tabs permissions shows the warning "Read your browsing history", when [on their documentation they clearly state](https://chrome-apps-doc2.appspot.com/extensions/permission_warnings.html) that it should show "Access your tabs and browsing activity" which makes much more sense.

If I had to install an extension that is suppose to save my tabs, but instead asks to read my browsing history, I wouldn't trust it at all. How am I suppose to gain users' trust? Is there another way around this?

Even if I remove all `chrome.tabs` code or use `chrome.windows` instead, I still get this warning. Could it be that they have a bug and it is showing the wrong warning message?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings which is the correct URL:

> "tabs": Read your browsing history

Technically this permission allows observing the history via chrome.tabs.onUpdated, but not read the previously existing history, so the phrasing is not entirely correct, strictly speaking.

As for user gesture + [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) it only grants access to the tab where the gesture occurred, not to all tabs.

Comment: I don't know how I ended up on "appspot.com" documentation, I guess this was old docs because it redirects to cloud.google.com. Thanks for directing me to the right ones. So it seems like there's no way around this right? Best option is to clearly warn the user beforehand, and maybe even open-source my code for those who want to be extra sure.

Comment: Yes, an explainer for all used permissions is quite a common thing for extension readme nowadays.